# Linux DST confusion

Tags: linux, timezone, dst

My question is about Daylight Savings Time (DST), and whether or not the following is behaviour is normal under Linux.  I am using the POSIX `TZ` variable to specify the timezone.

Using the example from [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html) man page, I set the TZ variable as follows:

`export TZ="NZST-12:00:00NZDT-13:00:00,M10.1.0,M3.3.0"`

After setting this environment variable, I can use `date` to set the time, and then watch the clock tick over into DST.  And that works out just fine (the name changes from `NZST` to `NZDT`, and we "lose" an hour of sleep).

```
Sun Oct  4 01:59:57 NZST 2015
Sun Oct  4 01:59:58 NZST 2015
Sun Oct  4 01:59:59 NZST 2015
Sun Oct  4 01:59:59 NZST 2015
Sun Oct  4 03:00:00 NZDT 2015
Sun Oct  4 03:00:01 NZDT 2015
```

But when I set the `date` to just before the end of DST, that's when I experience odd behaviour.  For example, if I set the time like so:

```
date --set="20 MAR 2016 0:59:50"
Sun Mar 20 00:59:50 NZDT 2016
```

We're still good.  But if I crank the clock forward slightly to `1:00:50` (just past 1:00am) we see a problem:

```
date --set="20 MAR 2016 1:00:50"
Sun Mar 20 01:00:50 NZST 2016
```

We've jumped out of `NZDT` and back into `NZST` too early.  But if I set the system back to `0:59:50` and (patiently) wait, it does not jump out of `NZDT` too early, and it'll roll back to `NZST` at the right time.

Is this normal system behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the problem is with how the transition is handled but that the time specified in the command `date --set="20 MAR 2016 1:00:50"` is ambiguous.

Ie, that time occurs twice; first before the transition out of DST and then again when the clock has jumped back an hour.
I'm unfortunately not sure how one would specify which occurrence of that time is desired (can the timezone be included to disambiguate it?).

Comment: Hi Håkan.  I totally agree with you that the time is ambiguous.  But bizarrely, I found that if I replicate this situation, but using a timezone which is to the West of the Prime Meridian (eg. CST(USA) UTC -6:00), the 'early exit' from DST doesn't happen.  You can try it.

Comment: Here's an example which I found on the IBM support pages - `TZ=CST6CDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00`.  Using this string, I don't see the symptoms described in my original post.  Switch the "6" for a "-6" however, and you can see the symptom occur.